# How to programmatically surf on a web page like a human from Windows application?

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, web-crawler

I need to surf on a web page using a C# window application (with a browser tool on it), and collect information for my data mining project. I need a tool that help me invoke events like click and refer to objects with a jQuery or css selectors like syntax to read them and save in database.

I try watin but that is just for testing my own web application.

Comment: The question isn't really [tag:data-mining] related. Please use more appropriate tags, such as [tag:screen-scraping].

Comment: Thank you Anony-Mousse for your attention, although it isn't directly related with data mining but many data mining projects needs to get information from web pages, and I think it's related with data-mining

Comment: Maybe even more data mining is done on sales data; this doesn't make sales relevant for data mining. All data needs to be generated somehow; this isn't really relevant for the statistics applied to it.
P.S. Make sure you do not violate the terms of use of the web site that you are scraping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try Selenium...

We use it for automated Regression Testing

http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Thank you for your response, 
Actually I don't want to test, I need to surf on any social web site and collect information, for my dm project, can I use that program for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, if you integrate Selenium with Visual Studio you can simulate clicks on a web site and grab any information from it.

Answer (score 2):

We sometimes use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for web scraping.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Actually I don't want to test, I need to surf on any social web site and collect information, for my dm project, can I use that program for this purpose?